# Can $S^2$ be given a (semi-)topological quasigroup structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, manifolds, topological-groups, quasigroups

It is known from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829928/can-s2-be-turned-into-a-topological-group) question that $S^2$ cannot be made into a topological group. Indeed, $S^2$ cannot even be made into an [$H$-Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-space), a much looser requirement than a topological group.

However, an $H$-Space does require an identity element, so I was wondering if different loose requirements could allow some somewhat nice multiplication on $S^2$. In particular, does there exist a continuous product $m:S^2\times S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ such that $(S^2,m)$ is a quasigroup? If this does exist, can we also require that the left and right division operations associated with this quasigroup are also continuous, making $S^2$ a topological quasigroup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, in a very precise sense $S^2$ cannot support **any** nontrivial algebraic structure! This was proved by Walter Taylor in his paper [*Spaces and equations*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm164/fm16431.pdf). And the situation doesn't change even if we allow equations to be satisfied only "up to error" - see [this old question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173065/what-sorts-of-sets-of-equations-are-approximately-compatible-with-the-2-sp).